# ElasticSearch - filter terms for autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch

I would like for an autocomplete to get the terms starting with some specific characters.However, the terms returned do not begin with the specified text ("wer" in this case), and more than that, no matter what the prefix content is, they are always the same.  The query I am using now is:

```
  {"facets":
      {"count":
          {"terms":
                {"field":"content"},
                 "facet_filter":
                     {"prefix":{"content":"wer"}}
          }
      },
    "size":0
  }
```

I am wondering what am I missing or doing wrong. Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you miss a "query" entry after the facet_filter.
If this does not help try regex pattern for facets, but be aware that facets will be removed in future updates of elasticsearch.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html#_regex_patterns